# linq sql find duplicates but take null and empty string as the same

Tags: c#, linq, null, duplicates

I have a half a half a million records table, that i need to find the duplicates. So i use this code i created:

```
var dups2 = from m in mg_B
    group m by new { m.Addr1, m.Addr2, m.City, m.State }
    into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

The problem with this code is that it will not take as duplicates 2 records that have addr1 as an empty string "" and respectively NULL.

Basically when comparing a null and an empty value of the field, it sees them as different, but i need to to be seen as the same.

I know i could go through every single record and replace the null values with "" but i took the computer 1 minute to go through 4 000 records. and this will be done repeatedly when someone clicks a button.

I found out about this null empty string issue because i initially created a class with just some of the fields (the table has over 40 fields).

```
List<CombineClass> mg = (from m in db.MG_Backup
   where m.IsArchived == false
   select new CombineClass { id = m.ID, name = m.Name, addr1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Addr1) ? "" : m.Addr1, addr2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Addr2) ? "" : m.Addr2, city = m.City, state = m.State }).ToList();
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What happens in the second example? Are you saying that one works but is undesirable because you have to _check_ and _act_ upon it? An empty string and null are very different things, and you can't tell the language to treat them otherwise, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: in the first example it finds 6000 records and in the second example finds over 7000 records

Comment: You could implement your own [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx) by implementing [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx). Your comparer will then perform the comparison how **you** want it, by treating null and empty string as the same. I doubt it would be fast though - it would still have to pull all the records from the database and process them C# side. Your best bet would be to fix the database to only have `NULL` for records where you do not have an AddrLine1 (as that would be semantically correct).

Comment: @Nathan The first and second examples won't return the same record count because of the `where g.Count > 1` condition in the first. See if you get the same counts if you remove that filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version is compatible with Linq-to-Sql / Linq-to-Entities

```
var dups2 = from m in mg_B
    group m by new 
    { 
        Addr1 = m.Addr1 ?? string.Empty, 
        Addr2 = m.Addr2 ?? string.Empty, 
        City  = m.City ?? string.Empty, 
        State = m.State ?? string.Empty,
    }
    into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

The generated sql looks a bit like this:

```
-- Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p2 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p4 Int = 1

SELECT [t2].[value2] AS [Addr1], [t2].[value22] AS [Addr2], [t2].[value3] AS [City], [t2].[value3] AS [State]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t1].[value] AS [value2], [t1].[value2] AS [value22], [t1].[value3], [t1].[value4]
    FROM (
        SELECT COALESCE([t0].[Addr1],@p0) AS [value], COALESCE([t0].[Addr2],@p1) AS [value2], COALESCE([t0].[City],@p2) AS [value3], COALESCE([t0].[State],@p3) AS [value4]
        FROM [SettingSystemNodes] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].[value], [t1].[value2], [t1].[value3], [t1].[value4]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE [t2].[value] > @p4
```

Note that you if you set `string.Empty` to a local variable before or even a `let` variable inside the query, only one parameter will be used for the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the brute force way:

```
var dups2 = from m in mg_B
    group m by new { 
        Addr1 = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Addr1) ? "" : m.Addr1), 
        Addr2 = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Addr2) ? "" : m.Addr2), 
        City  = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.City)  ? "" : m.City ), 
        State = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.State) ? "" : m.State),
        ...
        }
    into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

If you want the code to *look* cleaner you could have an extension method on `string`:

```
public static string EmptyForNull(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "" : s;
}
```

and then your query would be:

```
var dups2 = from m in mg_B
    group m by new { 
        Addr1 = EmptyForNull(m.Addr1), 
        Addr2 = EmptyForNull(m.Addr2), 
        City  = EmptyForNull(m.City), 
        State = EmptyForNull(m.State),
        ...
        }
    into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

However, this would probably be a LOT faster if it were done in SQL rather than Linq.

Comment: this was the first thing i tried before writing the post and it doesnt work... it just makes the criteria "" or addr1...

Comment: Nooooo! My eyes are bleeding! Use null coalescing, it properly translates to ISNULL. `Addr1 = m.Addr1 ?? string.Empty`